# Import JSON file in Javascript using Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-4

I have a file called `generic-map.json` containing the following:

```js
[
    {
        "names": ["text", "description"],
        "map": {
            "name": "textContent",
            "target": "property",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    {
        "names": ["checked"],
        "map": {
            "name": "checked",
            "target": "property",
            "type": "boolean"
        }
    },
    {
        "names": ["disabled", "readonly"],
        "map": {
            "name": "disabled",
            "target": "property",
            "type": "boolean"
        }
    },
    {
        "names": ["title", "tooltip"],
        "map": {
            "name": "title",
            "target": "property",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    {
        "names": ["cssclass", "classname"],
        "map": {
            "name": "",
            "target": "classList",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    {
        "names": ["tabindex"],
        "map": {
            "name": "tabIndex",
            "target": "attribute",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
]
```

In a Javascript file I'm trying to import this file:

```
import generic from './generic-map.json';
```

Webpack gives me **the following error**:

```
./src/utils/property-mapping/generic-map.json
Module parse failed: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 733 while parsing near '...type": "string" } }];'
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in JSON at position 733 while parsing near '...type": "string" } }];'
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I do know that webpack does no longer need `json-loader`, beginning with Webpack version 2.0.0. I'm using **Webpack 4.20.2**.

This is what my loaders configuration looks like:

```
[{
    test: /(\.js)/,
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    loaders: ['babel-loader'],
}, {
    test: /(\.jpg|\.png)$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
}]
```

Comment: did you try adding file-loader rule? like '{
   type: 'javascript/auto',
    test: /\.(json)/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    use: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
    }],
  }'

Comment: Is there a rogue semicolon at the end of your JSON file?

Comment: @madebydavid No, the JSON file is definitely correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `test: /(\.js)/` to `test: /\.js$/` or `test: /\.jsx?$/`

babel-loader process a .json file because of wrong test expression.